# Selecting JSON data from a single MySQL table field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

I have a PHP REST Web service which I am accessing from JavaScript.  If am running a MySQL SELECT statement which selects a few text fields and then json_encode the returned array everything works as expected - I am getting an array of JSON objects.
I created a new field where I am storing a whole JSON string and I only want to select that field and then return array of those JSON objects which the SELECT query returns.  Is there an easy way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Mysql doesn't have built-in support for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column then use json_decode on the result.

Comment: That's not particularly helpful.

Comment: @shapeshifter: that doesn't work, in this case I am getting an object within an object- an object created with json_decode with a single member, named the same as MySQL field, which contains the original object.